# Alignment Issue in UL while using Jquery - UL alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a simple parking layout application. I have completed the HTML layout and it looks decent as shown below.

[image: before]

But, after adding jQuery my layout goes crazy as shown below....

Actual Output:

[image: after]

Here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/arokiaantony/1edk2xku/ that shows what I've done.

```
...
```

I am very new to jQuery so if I am making a mistake kindly help me resolve.

Thanks a Lot!

Regards,
Arokia

Comment: can u re post your actual output image???

Comment: Hi Prabin Added in one image ...

Comment: When do you see this issue??? I checked jsfiddle and its all looking good there. How/When can i see that bug??

Comment: Even I am confused. When I launch it as a standalone HTML, this is happening.... but even in JS Fiddle it seems fine.... am I missing something...I am pretty much new to this... please help .... and the layout looks fine if I remove the JavaScript tag....

Comment: ok let me try out . Hold some minutes :)

Comment: Hi Prabin, Any luck... I see that the  left property of the list is getting altered automatically, I am not able to identify how or why .... 
could u please suggest me an alternative way for doing the same please ??

Comment: I really couldnt repro that bug so i'm finding hard to fix it. if you can show me the buggy code(when i run , i can see that bug) then it would be very usefull for me to solve it :)

Comment: Hi Prabin, I am trying to attach the file, please find the link attached  : https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FC34B90FB4172C5!13129&authkey=!AMi-KXYcKg4LWH0&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: I did check your file. I opened in IE, Chrome, FireFox and Safari and everywhere it's looking good.  http://tinypic.com/r/r8b2oi/9

Comment: Sorry not able to open your link..... 
But how is it possible Prabin, I am not able to understand. In JSFiddle its working fine, even in your system it is working fine but why not in mine :(    I too tried in Firefox, Chrome.... u r suppose to run "Untitled HTML 3.html" , you will see that the cars are closing in on each.... 

I'm goin crazy because of this :(

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iblWW.png

Comment: Well try resetting your cache .  Press Ctrl+F5 . I think its cache issue

Comment: No ... It didn work ... its the same ... I have no idea why it is so... 
need to figure out a quick fix for this ...  

please suggest something experts.....

Comment: Ok i'm out of it. :) Good luck

Comment: Appreciate your good effort Prabin! Hopefully I will fix it sooner ...

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.... thanks prabin again for helping me out....the issue was with the Javascript where again the width of the image was set back to 35 where in it shd be 51 px.